# concurrent POST requests seemingly not retrieving data completely

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, server, puppeteer

I have been using the following tutorial to build a full stack web scraping project using puppeteer:

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FjhF6Hy9gY
github: https://github.com/aj-4/setuptourist

Briefly, I have a simple front end that does a post request, and in the backend (node), I use `express` and have a app.post which is responsible for running a function that uses puppeteer to scrape some website. The error I am receiving, is that when 2 or more POST requests are called on and are executing within the same time frame my server seems to attempt running the two concurrently, but is not providing thorough responses.

**Here is my exact code:**

In my post method inside `index.js` (my server):

```
app.post("/data", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("Connected");
    const result = await scrapers.scrape();
    console.log("data" + result);
    res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});
```

In my `scrapers.js` file:

```
async function scrape() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const all_data= [];

  //traverse through first 4 pages of website
  for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    await page.goto(
      "https://www.examplewebsite.com/page" + i
    );

    const data = await page.evaluate(function () {
      const events = document.querySelectorAll(".a");
      const cur_data= [];

      for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        cur_data.push(events[i].innerText);
      }
      return cur_data;
    });

    all_data.push(data);
  }

  browser.close();

  return all_data;
}
```

**What I tried:** Two posts requests, the second request sent before the first one has terminated.

**What I expect:** To return the data from the website in it's entirety twice (one for each POST request)

**What I actually get:** Two data sets that are either partially completed, or one fully completed and the other empty.

I've spend the last few days researching how servers work, and I'm at a loss for why this would be happening in my case, where I have async functions and await calls to ensure I would be properly executing to receive the data.

Comment: `for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {` <-- `i` here is a global. Use `let i` to scope it locally so the two function calls aren't fighting over the same variable. ESlint will catch this sort of thing. Also `await browser.close()` and put it in a `finally` block so that you won't leak memory if the scrape throws.

Comment: Oh wow, great catch, thank you. Have to say I'm a little disappointed in myself for this one lol. Good point on the browser.close()/finally block as well.